# How to get rid of all ylabels of all subplots.[matplotlib]

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I would like to know how to get rid of all labels of all subplots. I have a dataframe consisting of 37 columns. Then, to make histograms for them, I wrote this code.

```
p_variables.plot.hist(subplots=True,layout=(5,8),figsize=(20,20),sharex=False,ylabel="")
plt.show()
```

I expected that all of ylabels of subplots were invisible by setting `ylabel=""`. However, they do not disappear. Could someone give me idea how to solve this?

The output is below. I would like to get rid of `Frequency` labels.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to iterate over the returned axes and set the ylabel to "" explicitly.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(40, 5), columns=list("ABCDE"))
axes = df.plot.hist(subplots=True,layout=(5,8),figsize=(20,20),sharex=False)

for ax in axes.flatten():
    ax.set_ylabel("")

plt.show()
```

[image]